# Pairing with BLE peripheral with no PIN?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

We are working on android device which acts like a peripheral and we need desktop apps to connect **to our android device over BLE**. I've read [android BLE docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)  I can't figure our is there "pairing" with BLE devices? Does the user or code have to pass PIN to connect BLE peripheral:

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

PS. I know Peripheral role for BLE device is supported starting Android 5.0

Comment: quick google search of "pin pairing with ble" gave: https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/LE-Security.aspx

Comment: can you point where pairing mode is set in Android API (peripheral mode)?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with Android